# Floyd's Algorithm Explanation

Tags: algorithm, floyd-warshall

Concerning

```
floyds(int a[][100],int n).
```

What does 'a' and represent and what does each of the two dimensions of a represent?

What does 'n' represent?

I have a list of locations, with a list of connections between those locations and have computed the distance between those connections that are connect to each other.  Now I need to find shortest path between any given two locations (floyd's) - but need to understand how to apply `floyds(int a[][100],int n)` to my locations array, city dictionaries, and connection arrays.

FYI - Using objective C - iOS.

Comment: It would help if you told us where you found that function declaration.

Comment: Kurt - I had mentioned where I found it in the notes below.  (Why am I getting down votes?) Here it is again: prabhakargouda.hubpages.com/hub/floyds-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is the number of nodes in the graph.

`a` is an [distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) of the graph. `a[i][j]` is the cost (or distance) of the edge from node i to node j.

(Also read the definition of [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) if you need more help with the concept.)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Assume a function edgeCost(i,j) which returns the cost of the edge from i to j

2    (infinity if there is none).

3    Also assume that n is the number of vertices and edgeCost(i,i) = 0

4 */

5

6     int path[][];

7     /* A 2-dimensional matrix. At each step in the algorithm, path[i][j] is the shortest path

8        from i to j using intermediate vertices (1..k−1).  Each path[i][j] is initialized to

9        edgeCost(i,j).

10     */

12     procedure FloydWarshall ()

13        for k := 1 to n

14           for i := 1 to n

15              for j := 1 to n

16                 path[i][j] = min ( path[i][j], path[i][k]+path[k][j] );
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall

wiki is very good~~~

Comment: The link you provide does not have a function header like the one I asked about [floyds(int a[][100],int n)].  I found a version of the implementation here http://prabhakargouda.hubpages.com/hub/floyds-algorithm which had a function header as follows : floyds(int a[][100],int n), hence my initial question.

Comment: p.s.  Given my inputs are source, destination, number of vertices (locations), which locations any location is connected to, and finally the cost or distance associated with any two directed connections, which of these go to a[] and a[][] and n?

Answer (score 0):

```
floyd-warshall(W) // W is the adjacent matrix representation of graph..
 n=W.rows;
 for k=1 to n
    for i=1 to n
       for j=1 to n
            w[i][j]=min(W[i][j],W[i][k]+W[k][j]);
 return W;
```

It's a dp-algorithm.At the k-th iteration here W[i][j] is the shortest path between i and j and the vertices of the shortest path(excluding i and j) are from the set {1,2,3...,k-1,k}.In min(W[i][j],W[i][k]+W[k][j]), W[i][j] is the computed shortest path between i and j at k-1-th iteration and here since the intermediate vertices are from the set {1,2...k-1},so this path does not include vertex k. In W[i][k]+W[k][j],we include vertex k in the path.whichever between the two is minimum is the shortest path at k-th iteration.
Basically we check that whether we should include vertex k in the path or not.